# How to use custom themes in angular components

Tags: angular, themes, scss-mixins

How can i use the primary and accent color of a custom theme in my component.scss?

styles.scss:

```
@import './themes';
```

themes.scss:

```
@import 'app/my.component.theme.scss';

@mixin my-components-theme($theme) {
  @include my-component-theme($theme);
  // ...
}

@mixin set-theme($theme) {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme);
  @include container($theme);
  @include flex-container-column();
  @include my-components-theme($theme);
}

// Theme MY Indigo / Red
$my-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$my-theme-accent:  mat-palette($mat-red);

$my-light-theme:   mat-light-theme($my-theme-primary, $my-theme-accent);

.my-light-theme {
  @include set-theme($my-light-theme);
}
```

my.component.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin my-component-theme($theme) {
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);
    $background: map-get($theme, background);
    .test-class {
        background-color: mat-color($primary, 1) !important;
    }
}
```

I now would expect that in my component html an element with the class 'text-class' would have a red background color. But the class is not even set, i can't inspect it with chrome dev tools.

Comment: i think i have found the problem: i used the class in an devextreme popup. Outside of that popup it works, inside not yet.